# Simple query with one value, but get Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql, pdo

This is array to insert

```
Array ( [0] => Other property, plant and equipment )
```

And this is query

```
INSERT INTO 1_1_chartofaccounts (LocationInBalanceorPLS) VALUES (?);
```

Get

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

What is wrong?

At first code was following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
```

Then changed to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $insertData);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now do not see error. However do not understand why in first example get error

Comment: I believe `execute()` accepts no input or an array (see: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)). So `$stmt->execute( array($insertData));` would have worked I guess. Have you tried your array with index 1 for the data? :)

Comment: It appears that made stupid mistakes (set conditions and get unexpected result) creating `$insertData`. Changed conditions and all works as expected